# NIS / YP make - mail.aliases Callback timed out

Tags: nameserver, nis, yp

I am trying to add the mail.aliases map to my Makefile on my NIS/YP server. I have added 'mail' to list of maps to build, and ensured that it is pointing to the correct aliases file (/etc/aliases).

The problem I am getting is that when I run make, I get a "Callback timed out" error like the following:

> mail.aliases -> "SlaveNisServer": Callback timed out

The other maps seem to build successfully.

Does anyone have any idea what could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

It's possible your slave server is not set up correctly - Try running ypinit on the SlaveNisServer, and ensure that the NIS (and rpcbind) daemons are running:

```
/usr/lib/yp/ypinit -s MasterNisServer
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. Helped to solve the issue:

```
# /usr/lib64/yp/ypinit -s nfs1
We will need a few minutes to copy the data from nfs1.
Transferring protocols.bynumber...
Trying ypxfrd ... success

Transferring services.byname...
Trying ypxfrd ... success

Transferring group.bygid...
Trying ypxfrd ... success

Transferring auto.data...
Trying ypxfrd ... success

Transferring mail.aliases...
Trying ypxfrd ... success

Transferring auto.app...
Trying ypxfrd ... success

Transferring netid.byname...
Trying ypxfrd ... success

Transferring ypservers...
Trying ypxfrd ... success

Transferring auto.home...
Trying ypxfrd ... success

Transferring rpc.byname...
Trying ypxfrd ... success

Transferring hosts.byname...
Trying ypxfrd ... success

Transferring passwd.byname...
Trying ypxfrd ... success

Transferring auto.master...
Trying ypxfrd ... success

Transferring passwd.byuid...
Trying ypxfrd ... success

Transferring hosts.byaddr...
Trying ypxfrd ... success

Transferring rpc.bynumber...
Trying ypxfrd ... success

Transferring group.byname...
Trying ypxfrd ... success

Transferring protocols.byname...
Trying ypxfrd ... success

Transferring services.byservicename...
Trying ypxfrd ... success


nfs2's NIS data base has been set up.
If there were warnings, please figure out what went wrong, and fix it.
```

At this point, make sure that `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` have
been edited so that when the NIS is activated, the databases you
have just created will be used, instead of the `/etc` ASCII files.
`[root@nfs2:/root]`

Also run: **service ypserv restart**
This will update the ypserv settings.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after I added a new file to the NIS system. I copied the generated binary file manually and after that that it gets synced on the slave. Clearly the pointed out ypinit also recopies the file again.